# android TextView.setText Nullpointer Exception(android beginner)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list,null);
    }
    // GET VIEWS
    TextView nameTxt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
    TextView landTxt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.landtxt);
    TextView groesseTxt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groessetxt);
    TextView gewichtTxt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gewichttxt);
    ImageView img =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    //SET DATA
    nameTxt.setText(names[position]);
    landTxt.setText(land[position]);
    groesseTxt.setText(groesse[position]);
    gewichtTxt.setText(gewicht[position]);
    img.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

[I can't start my program of the NullPointerException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hKjJ.png)

[image]

I want to create a custom listview, with a onClick to a new Activity...

Comment: one of these `nameTxt` `landTxt` `groesseTxt` `gewichTxt` is null

Comment: Which line throws an exception?

Comment: The problem is probably that one of your arrays is null

Comment: Not sure which line is line 98...

Comment: Post the code of this layout `program_list`

Comment: thank you guys, i have solved the problem, the program_list was not complete. But now i have another problem. How can I declare a new Activity in Manifast.xml. So i can get to another Activity with an onClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debug this code:

```
TextView nameTxt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
TextView landTxt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.landtxt);
TextView groesseTxt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groessetxt);
TextView gewichtTxt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gewichttxt);
ImageView img =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Maybe they views (`nametxt,landtxt,groessetxt,gewichttxt,imageView1`) dont exist in program_list layout.

Answer (score 0):

check your layout (R.layout.program_list) if contain the id nametxt, landtxt, groessetxt and gewichttxt probably this is the error, someone is missing in the line 98.

if all exist, the other thing is some array contain null values.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your textviews are not belongs to your layout. Make sure you have provided same ids in your layout file.